# cshtml selectlistitem get option value not dropdown value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a simple select list item that is pushed into a dropdownlist.

Here is the HTML results

```
<select id="Options" name="Options"><option value="">Options</option>
<option value="1">Option1</option>
<option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Basically I have this simple javascript script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".option").each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        var id = $("#Options").val();
        $("#_" + id).show();

        $("#Options").change(function () {
            $(".option").each(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
            var id = $(this).val();
            $("#_" + id).show();
        });
    });
```

and basically this will show a different option changing my html to hide and show, but basically what I want to do is, when the user selects an option from the dropdownlist, it will get the option name value so "Option1", I can then use this is a different way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get selected option text you need:

```
$(this).find(":selected").text();// will be options,option1,option2 etc.
```